# where is a bug in my startup mounting application in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, startup-applications

In the Terminal, the command

```
myuser@TomE:~$ sleep 5 && /home/myuser/mountF
myuser@TomE:~$
```

works OK with mountF containing

```
#! /bin/bash
pkexec mount -t vfat /dev/sdb7 /home/myuser/F
```

. But if I place the same command in the Startup Applications dialog and check it, it does not work after I log in, even if I have unchecked the antivirus program there and disconnected external USB disks. In my home directory is a file .xsession-errors, with the logging time,  containing

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

. Is it related to this problem? (According to the Software Updater, my system is up to date.) Thanks!

Comment: use sudo rather then pkexec as mount is not a graphical tool. Also better to mount by UUID or label rather then /dev/sdb7, but that is minor. Did you configure sudo to run without a password ? Probably the best solution is to add an entry to fstab using the options noauto and users then you can mount without sudo. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to /etc/fstab

sudo nano /etc/fstab

Add in

```
/dev/sdb7 /home/myuser/F vfat noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8  0  0
```

Now you can mount at login with or without a script and without sudo

```
mount /dev/sdb7
```

So just run that command, `mount /dev/sdb7` at login, no need for a script or anything complex.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab for details and other options.

Comment: I have changed the command in the mountF file to 'mount /dev/sdb7' only, left it checked in the Startup Applications dialog and added that '/dev/sdb7 /home/myuser/F vfat noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8  0  0' row at the end of the /etc/fstab. After restart and login as the myuser, the directory /home/myuser/F appears to be empty. In Terminal, after the command from the question, the /home/myuser/F directory denies access. Moreover I need to use the /dev/sdb7 partition also as another user, e.g. as the root. Thanks!

Comment: Well, FAT partitions do not support permissions and IMO if you are using the partition as root I would mount it elsewhere. At any rate, you set the permissions at the time of mount , options would be uid=0, gid=0,dmask and fmask are probably fine. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab and man mount for details or ask a new question with the details you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the mount command is not run at login even without the pkexec : the directory /home/myuser/F is then permitted for myuser. How can I achieve running  a similar mounting command at login?

Comment: I can not tell from what you have posted and your user case seems complicated. Ask a new question, post your fstab, run the mount command in a terminal and any error. To some extent I think half your problem is permissions and the other half is you are trying to mount at login in rather then boot.

Comment: The general question about it is https://askubuntu.com/questions/949848/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-partition-as-a-common-depository-for-users-with-the-sa