# Is it possible to mount a partition as a common depository for users with the same relative path?

Tags: 16.04, startup-applications

I have installed Ubuntu system at an SS disk and I have a lot of files that need also another (mechanical) disk. I wish users to access a common 
depository partition with identical relative path from their home directories. I hoped that it can be achieved by mounting that common partition at each user login ([where is a bug in my startup mounting application in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949491/where-is-a-bug-in-my-startup-mounting-application-in-ubuntu-16-04)). Is it possible at all,  without necessity for each user to mount it manually? How to run such a mounting at login? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to do a specific mount for each user? An other solution could be to mount the partition via `/etc/fstab` and to symlink that mountpoint to somewhere in the user's home.

Comment: @ ridgy:    My problem started by upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04; in fact, I wish to use the second disk the same way as I have used FAT32 media. Before, each particular medium, e.g. flash_3, was referred as /media/flash_3, in the 16.04 version it is referred as /media/myuser/flash_3 with permissions particular to the myuser. 
   Maybe I had misused the FAT32 not supporting permissions. What is the correct Linux way how to yield all users (in fact me as a standard user and me as the Administrator) the same read/write permission for the common directory files? Thanks!

Comment: @ ridgy: Probably I should learn how to use group rights. Years ago, my intuitive attempt had failed. Does 'info group' command lead to the sufficient information about read/write permissions? Thanks!

Comment: I have asked another question about it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/950436/how-to-yield-all-users-the-read-write-permission-for-files-in-a-the-common-direc

Comment: Well, you have two problems. Why do you not just mount it at boot if you want all users to have access ? It really makes no sense to have each user mount it individually at login. The option "users" in fstab will do what you want (allow users to mount / unmount the partition). Second problem is you are trying to set up a shared drive using FAT, you really need to use a linux native file system as FAT does not use permissions. To setup a shared directory I highly advise ACL - https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/how-do-i-set-up-a-folder-so-that-anything-created-in-it-inherits-permissions